# How to convert decimals to two's complement string

Tags: c++

I am really new to C++ and I am a bit confused on my program.
The program is supposed to take 2 integers and convert them to two's complement strings with an L-size bit, but when I run the program I keep getting a string subscript out of range error.
I might have a lot of mistakes and it would be great if you guys can point out some big mistakes.
My program:

```
string reverse(string s) 
{
    string x="";
for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    x += s[i];
}
    return x;
}
string twosComplementStringAddition(string a,string b)
{
    string c;
    int count;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if(count>0)
            c[i]='1';
        else if(a[i]=='1' & b[i]=='1')
        {
            c[i]='0';
            count++;
        }
        else if((a[i]=='1' & b[i]=='0')|| (a[i]=='0' & b[i]=='1'))
            c[i]='1';
        else if(a[i]=='0' & b[i]=='0')
            c[i]='0';
        count=0;
    }
    return c;
    }
    string negative(string a)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=='1')
            a[i]='0';
        else
            a[i]='1';
    }
    reverse(a);
    string x="1";
    twosComplementStringAddition(a,x);
    reverse(a);
    return a;
}
string decimalToTwosComplementString(int a, int L)
{
    string s="";
    L= s.length();
    int b;
        for(int i=0;i<L-1;i++)
        {
            b=a%2;
            if(b==1)
                s[i]='1';
            else if(b==0)
                s[i]='0';
            a=a/2;
        }
        reverse(s);
        if(a<0)
        {
            negative(s);
            return s;
        }
        else
        return s;
}
int twosComplementStringToDecimal(string a)
{
    int result=0;
    if(a[0]=='0')
    {
        reverse(a);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=='1')
        {
            result= result + pow(2,static_cast<float>(i));
        }
        else if(a[i]=='0')
        {
            result = result + 0;
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    negative(a);
    int resulta=0;
    reverse(a);
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
{
    if(a[i]=='1')
    {
    resulta= resulta + pow(2,static_cast<float>(i));
    }
    else if(a[i]=='0')
    {
        resulta = resulta + 0;
    }
}
return resulta;
}
return result;
}
int main()
{
//Read in the bit pattern size
int L;
do
{
    cout << "Enter positive integer for the bit pattern size ";
    cin >> L;
}while (L <= 0);

//Read in two integers a and b 
int a, b;
cout << "Enter an integer a ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter an integer b ";
cin >> b;

//Calculate the decimal arithmetic sum of a and b and print the result
int c1 = a + b;
cout << "In decimal " << a << " + " << b << " is " << c1 << endl;

//Compute the two's complement representations of a and b
//Each integer must be represented in L-bits pattern
//Also these two's complement representations must be returned as string data types
string A = decimalToTwosComplementString(a, L);
string B = decimalToTwosComplementString(b, L);

//Print the two's complement representations of a and b
cout << "The two's complement of " << a << " is\t " << A << endl;
cout << "The two's complement of " << b << " is\t " << B << endl;

//Compute the binary sum of the two's complement representations of a and b
//The result must be returned as L-bit pattern string data type
string C = twosComplementStringAddition(A, B);

//Print the two's complement representation binary sum
cout << "The binary sum of " << A << " and " << B << " is " << C << endl;

//Convert the two's complement representation binary sum to decimal and print
int c2 = twosComplementStringToDecimal(C);
cout << "In two's complement arithmetic, " << a << " + " << b << " is " << c2 << endl;
system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

For anyone willing to help, thank you for your time!
Edit:
After a few hours, I finally made it work, thank you guys for helping a beginner out!

Comment: What sort of errors?

Comment: Hello! I am afraid "keep getting errors" is too much generic. The error logs of the compiler usually are useful to debug stuff. Try to narrow the problems and be more specific, you hardly find somebody which will debug all your code.

Comment: it says string subscript out of range when I run it

Comment: `int main() { std::string c; c[0] = 'x'; }` -- See anything wrong with that small program?  You're making the same mistake in your code, i.e. why your program is giving you an out of range error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm sorry I don't know, isn't that suppose to mean to assign 'x' and the string at index 0?

Comment: There is no index 0.  The string is empty.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh okay thanks.

Comment: If you add the "-Wsign-conversion" to your compile command, it will report many warnings.   Adding "-Wsign-compare" will report most of your for-loops.  You should also consider adding -Wfloat-conversion.

Comment: @2785528 Sorry, but how do I do that with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express? I have not learned anything like that yet.

Comment: I have no idea.  But you might try some research ... "how add/change g++ options in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express" (Hint: maybe this quote can be submitted to your browser?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting out with an empty string, and attempting to access items in the string that are non-existing:

```
string c;
//...
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
{ 
   //...
   c[i]='0'; // <-- The string is empty, but you're trying to access element i.
   //...
}
```

To fix the error, resize the `c` string to the appropriate size, so that those entries exist.

```
string c;
c.resize(a.length());
//..
```

.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping.